# Which method is used to solve following indefinite integral?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

$$\int \frac{x + \sin x}{\sqrt {\tan x } + \cos x} dx$$

I tried using substitution and rationalize but nothing works. And I do not how to solve this one. Please help me.

Comment: is it a definite integral? Where are the limits

Comment: Sorry my mistake. It's indefinite.

Comment: Hint: $\int\dfrac{dx}{\sqrt{\tan x}+\cos x}$
http://www.integral-calculator.com/#expr=1%2F%28%28tanx%29%5E%281%2F2%29%2Bcosx%29

Comment: @Amar are you sure it is doable?

Comment: or is this a troll xD?

Comment: wolfram alpha can't do it

Comment: (tan x) is definable in –π/2< x < π/2 . Let’s consider the function in range near zero: 0-ε< x < 0 + ε. In the case   x≈ sin x≈ tan x and cos x ≈1, then the function reduces to simple form 
2x/(√(x ) +1). May be this could help for a rough estimation.

Comment: _Wolfram Mathematica_ gives an answer in terms of [`RootSum`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RootSum.html), [`EllipticPi`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EllipticPi.html) and [`PolyLog`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PolyLog.html) functions, and also some $\arcsin$, $\ln$, $\tan$ etc. The expression itself is quite large: https://pastebin.mozilla.org/9019767.

Comment: this integral is not elementary. another such example is sqrt(sin(x))

Comment: this cannot be solved

Answer (score 0):

Analysis using known programs indicates that the given integral does not have a closed representation through known functions. In addition, for negative tangent values ​​in the denominator, the integrand function ceases to be valid, and the statement of the problem does not contain recommendations for this case.

On the other hand, the function in the denominator is periodic.

Based on these considerations, the following should be done:

1) abandon the search for solutions in elementary functions;
2) explicitly identify the intervals where the function is valid;
3) replace the denominator by a factor in the form of an infinite Fourier series.

Under these conditions, you can get an acceptable result.